# Динамическое создание делегата определенного типа

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть задача - разработать алгоритм для генерации делегата, при этом все его параметры должны быть переданы в метод с сигнатурой `params object[] args`. Но в данном коде происходит ошибка:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type type = typeof(Action<string, int>);
    Delegate del = GenerateDelegate(type, typeof(Program).GetMethod("TestMethod"));
    del.DynamicInvoke("test",64);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static Delegate GenerateDelegate(Type t, MethodInfo mi)
{
    // нужно что-то при помощи Reflection.Emit, что бы создавало из Type и метода Delegate этого типа
}

public static void TestMethod(params object[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
}
```

Comment: Что за ошибка то?

Comment: Вы хотя бы компилирующийся код приведите. / И укажите: обычный .NET или Core?

Comment: Ошибка:
System.ArgumentException: Не удается привязать целевой метод, поскольку его сигнатура или прозрачность безопасности несовместима с сигнатурой или прозрачностью безопасности типа делегата. Обычный .NET. Код компилируется.

Comment: И сейчас код не компилируется. / Добавил public.

Comment: Проблема не с безопасностью, а с сигнатурой. `string, int` не равно `object[]`.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нет - при делегате Func все в порядке.

Comment: Не верю. Докажите.

Comment: Все-таки не совсем так, это только при делегате Func<object[], ...>. Насколько я понял, эту задачу можно решить исключительно при помощи Reflection.Emit?

Comment: А зачем создавать для метода, принимающего object[], делегат вида `Action<string, int>` только для того, чтобы вызвать его через DynamicInvoke (который все равно принимает object[])? Опишите реальную задачу.

Comment: Конечно же, не только для этого. Я разрабатываю генератор динамических делегатов для связки с другим ЯП, и нужно, чтобы из созданного при выполнении Action<string, int> вызывался статический метод object[].

Answer (score 5):

`args`, пусть даже и с `params` - это один аргумент типа `object[]`. Он не соответствует параметрам `Action<string, int>`.

Вы точно так же получите ошибку при обычном статическом объявлении делегата:

```
Action<string, int> del = TestMethod;
```

> error CS0123: No overload for 'TestMethod' matches delegate 'Action'

"Обычный" .NET код вида

```
TestMethod("test", 64);
```

компилируется только потому, что компилятор видит модификатор `params` у вызываемого метода и заменяет вызов на

```
TestMethod(new object[] { "test", 64 });
```

В случае делегата это не происходит, т.к. компилятор не может заранее знать, будет ли внутри делегата лежать метод с params, а вызов в результирующем коде должен выглядеть одинаково.

---

Если вам нужно преобразовывать параметры - придется генерировать обертки на лету, что-то вроде:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<string, int> del = CreateAction<string, int>(TestMethod);
    del.DynamicInvoke("test", 64);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// раскопипастить для разного количества T, по аналогии с Action
static Action<T1, T2> CreateAction<T1, T2>(Action<object[]> target)
{
    return (T1 a, T2 b) => target(new object[] { a, b });
}

public static void TestMethod(params object[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
}
```

Comment: Но как сделать такой делегат, чтобы все аргументы передавались в массив args?

Comment: @Antinet `Action<object[]>` ?

Comment: Нет, Action<string, int>.

Comment: Или нужно применять Reflection.Emit?

Comment: @Antinet вам же tym32167 написал выше - если вам нужен делегат, который будет передавать аргументы в args - то тип такого делегата должен быть Action<object[]>. Делегаты - это не "адаптеры" для типов параметров. Если вам нужно нечто, что будет принимать на вход два параметра, и внутри вызывать метод с одним параметром - это "нечто" должно быть отдельным методом.

Comment: Да, но задача такова, чтобы создать делегат из заранее неизвестного Type, который будет вызывать метод с params object[] args. По-видимому, нужно нестандартное решение.

Comment: @Antinet если общее количество аргументов ограничено (как для генериков Action<T, T, T>, например - они объявлены только до 16 аргументов) - то можно сделать генератор оберток в общем виде. Сейчас допишу в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но здесь применены статические возможности c#, а также известны аргументы метода Action. По моей задаче список аргументов заранее неизвестен, в метод надо передать Type делегата.

Comment: @Antinet делегат всегда с void return type? или нужно обрабатывать и возврат результата?

Comment: Сейчас с ним, я потом попробую и с возвратом.

Comment: Все-таки лучше Func<>.

Comment: @PashaPash, скорее всего, потребуется DynamicMethod, но как его использовать для этого?

Comment: @Antinet проще собрать лямбду на лету (через Expression.Call) - и скомпилировать. Сорри, времени не нашлось пример нарисовать.

Comment: Да, я уже делал так, но не получилось.